# Any experience with SwifUI NavigationView in landscape on iPhone XR simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, swiftui, iphone-xr

I tried running my app in landscape on an iPhone XR simulator and got a blank screen.

The code below is my test. It works correctly on an iPhone 8 simulator and also not the iPhone XR simulator if I remove the NavigationView.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { gp in
                VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.center) {
                    Text("Width: \(gp.size.width)")
                    Text("Height: \(gp.size.height)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that I will see the size of the screen in both landscape and portrait.

Does anyone have any experience with this combination?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. It is just that when a big iPhone is in landscape, its horizontal size class is set to `.regular`, instead of `.compact`. Think of it, as if it were an iPad.

You can verify it, by sliding from the left size of your screen:

[image]

If you change your code to add a default view when nothing is selected, you get this other look:

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { gp in
                VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.center) {
                    Text("Width: \(gp.size.width)")
                    Text("Height: \(gp.size.height)")
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Something got selected")) { Text("Select something") }
                }

            }

            Text("No Selection")
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to force it to .compact, you do the following:

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { gp in
                VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.center) {
                    Text("Width: \(gp.size.width)")
                    Text("Height: \(gp.size.height)")
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Something got selected")) { Text("Select something") }
                }

            }

            Text("No Selection")
        }.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .compact)
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I accept that that is what is happening but why only in a NavigationView?

Comment: That is just how they work. The same thing happens with `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this modifier to the NavigationView works disabling master - detail views.

```
NavigationView {
  // Code
}
.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .compact)
```

Comment: Thanks but that was exactly what @kontiki wrote.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to put a quick answer. I just started with stack overflow, sorry for the redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to force the NavigationView to stack style.

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Hello World")
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Or the newer:

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Hello World")
    }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```